# JavaScript issue with IE9 - Working without issue when Developer Toolbar is shown

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, coffeescript

I'm encountering quite a weird JavaScript Issue in IE9 (It works fine tough in Chrome, Safari, Firefox).

I have some JS that selects a different Color of an Image when you click on that associated swatch. In IE9, it seems that is completely ignoring this and it is simply doing nothing. But, as soon as I open up the F12 Developer Tools it starts working - Even without reloading the page. Am I mising something here?

**jQuery**

```
$('.product-details-description-colors .circle img').click(function() {

  if(!$(this).hasClass('oos')) {

    url = $(this).parent('label').data('image');
    color_value = $(this).parent('label').prev('input');
    color_value.prop('checked', true);

    $('.circle').find('input').not(color_value).attr('checked', false);
    $(this).css('outline', '1px solid black');
    $('.product-details-description-colors .circle img').not(this).css('outline', 'none');
    $('.product-details-images-showroom img').attr('src', url);

  }

});
```

Comment: Is this wrapped with the ready event? Are you using `console.`?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? And we'd be able to help further if you had some more code, maybe the `HTML` and `CSS`? Create a JS fiddle @ jsfiddle.net

Comment: From my understanding, isn't calling an anonymous jQuery function the same as calling (document).ready? - In addition to that, opening the console or having an output there wont help - As soon as I open the console on IE, it starts working.

Comment: Even when the developer tools are in a different window?  If this is fixed to your screen, see if the issue happens when changing your screen size - as that what the developer tools will be doing.

Comment: It works, even when the Developer Tools are in a different window - also when I resize the browser, it does not seem to make any changes. I'm completely lost on that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you haven't posted all your code. One of the most common causes of this is trying to use the `console` object, specifically `console.log`. This is only available when the F12 tools are open and if they aren't, it will cause mysterious errors from propagating `undefined`.

Hence, this is a good idea to put somewhere in your coffeescript app:

```
# Fix IE logging issues
if not window.console
  window.console = 
    log: ->
```

Comment: Removing the console.log debugging statements fixed that issue! Thank you!

Comment: Run that code above as the page loads and it'll work regardless of whether you remove your statements or not.